# what is meant by density of energy eigen states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am reading modern quantum mechanics by jj sakurai.

> To estimate (2.168) in a more concrete manner, let us suppose that the state ket can be regarded as a superposition of so many energy eigenkets with similar energies that we can regard them as exhibiting essentially a quasi-continuous spectrum. It is then legitimate to replace the sum by the integral
> $$\sum_{a'} \rightarrow \int dE \, \rho(E), \quad
> c_{a'} \rightarrow g(E) \Large \rvert_{E=E_{a'}}\,$$
> where $\rho(E)$ characterizes the density of energy eigenstates. Expression (2.1.68) now becomes
> $$C(t) = \int dE \left \lvert g(E) \right \rvert^2 \rho(E) \, \exp \left( \frac{-i E t}{\hbar}\right) \, .$$

what I understood from this is that density of energy eigenstates is the number of energy eigenstates present in a unit energy interval. multiplying it with dE gives the number of energy eigenstates in the interval dE. (g(E))^2 gives the probability of obtaining the energy eigenvalue E. The probability of obtaining an energy eigenvalue is constant in the interval dE. suppose there are two energy eigenstates in the interval dE then these two energy eigenstates will have the same probabilities of measurement. assume the probability of one of these eigenvalues is more than 0.5. Then the other will have a probability of more than 0.5. which doesn't make sense as all the probabilities of energy eigenstates add up to 1. what is wrong with understanding?

Comment: Your understanding of density of states is correct. $g(E)^2$ is not really a probablitiy, but a probability density (i.e. probability per unit energy). $g(E)^2\cdot dE$ is the probability of finding the systems energy to be in the interval $E+dE$. We cannot have probabilities larger than one, the integral must be normalized. This is assumed in the expression but can be explicitly done like this: $C(t) = \frac{\int dE \vert g(E)\vert^2 \rho(E)exp(\frac{-iEt}{\hbar})}{\int dE \vert g(E)\vert^2 \rho(E)}$